# Oracle 9i - Optimizer Issues with Date Arithmetic?

Tags: performance, oracle, oracle9i, ora-00932

We have a query that includes (but has other joins, tables and where conditions):

```
SELECT
    o.contact_id, 
    o.completed_date, 
    o.submitted_date
FROM
    orders o /* 860,000 row table */
WHERE   
    ? <= o.submitted_date
    AND o.submitted_date < ? + 1
```

called from a Java application.

The `?` paramaters allow checking for orders submitted between two dates.

However, this query runs very slowly.

We converted to run from PL/SQL for testing as follows:

```
SubmittedDateFrom date:=to_date('2011-07-15', 'yyyy-mm-dd');
SubmittedDateTo date:=to_date('2011-07-15', 'yyyy-mm-dd');
CURSOR c_orgs    IS    
SELECT
    o.contact_id, 
    o.completed_date, 
    o.submitted_date
FROM
    orders o
WHERE   
    SubmittedDateFrom <= o.submitted_date
    AND o.submitted_date < SubmittedDateTo + 1;
BEGIN
    FOR c_o IN c_orgs LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Submitted date = '||c_o.submitted_date);                               
    END LOOP;
END;
```

IF we either:

1. convert the `SubmittedDateTo` value to `to_date('2011-07-16', 'yyyy-mm-dd')` (i.e. do the arithmetic outside the query),
2. make `SubmittedDateTo` a string and use "`to_date('SubmittedDateTo', 'yyyy-mm-dd')` + 1" as the second condition in the `WHERE`.

THEN, the query speeds up dramatically ( < 1 second vs. 44+ seconds).

Further information:

- running an explain plan on the query gives the error `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER`
- the `submitted_date` column has an index and stats, etc. have been run
- wrapping the `SubmittedDateTo + 1` in a `trunc()` call does not affect performance
- We do not have a non-9i database with similar data volumes, etc. to test if it's the version of Oracle or not.

The question is: we are unable to find any information which clearly states that the Oracle 9i Optimizer has an issue with this kind of date arithmetic.  Is that what's happening here or is there something else going on?

Comment: Are you able to replicate the issue with a test case ( eg, a table built from dba_objects or the like ).

Comment: Haven't tried.  I have limited DB permission since I'm on the app-dev rather than the dba side of things...

Comment: Is your Java code binding a DATE or a STRING to the ?

Comment: We are binding to the ? with a `java.sql.Timestamp` object.  See under Ollie's question for what the real issue was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd always ensure that all conversions are handled explicitly (and assuming o.submitted_date is a DATE datatype):

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR c_orgs    
  IS
     SELECT o.contact_id,      
            o.completed_date,
            o.submitted_date 
       FROM orders o 
      WHERE o.submitted_date BETWEEN TO_DATE(SubmittedDateFrom, 'yyyy-mm-dd') 
                                 AND TO_DATE(SubmittedDateTo, 'yyyy-mm-dd'); 
BEGIN
   FOR c_o IN c_orgs 
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Submitted date = '||c_o.submitted_date);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

This ensures there is no errors in any implicit conversions and all conversions are obvious in their data type.

"The question is: we are unable to find any information which clearly states that the Oracle 9i Optimizer has an issue with this kind of date arithmetic. Is that what's happening here or is there something else going on?"

I don't think it is the optimiser, it could be the end product of your implicit conversions are causing the performance issues. As we do not have you NLS settings for dates etc from the Oracle database it'd be hard to tell but if using explicit conversions increases performance, then I'd suggest you use them (and it's better pracitce too).

Hope it helps, Ollie.

Comment: Ollie, I'm accepting the answer because you are correct in suggesting that this is not due to the optimizer.  I played with the query a little more and (in the bits that I didn't show), we had a redundant join into a table that we didn't give an index hint to which was dragging it down.  What's very strange is that **either** fixing the index **or** using the original query (with join/indexing issue) with the date arithmetic pre-calculated will speed up the query.  A slight bit faster if the join/index + pre-calculated arithmetic are both used.

Comment: Still scratching my head over why changing the date arithmetic covered over the indexing problem, though...

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Oracle documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10752/ex_plan.htm) (this is v10, but I guess this applies to 9i as well), "...does not support EXPLAIN PLAN for statements performing implicit type conversion of date bind variables."

Apart from the approach sugggested by Ollie, have you tried using trunc() resp. between instead?

```
SELECT
    o.contact_id, 
    o.completed_date, 
    o.submitted_date
FROM
    orders o /* 860,000 row table */
WHERE   
    trunc(o.submitted_date) = trunc(?)
```

resp.

```
SELECT
    o.contact_id, 
    o.completed_date, 
    o.submitted_date
FROM
    orders o /* 860,000 row table */
WHERE   
    o.submitted_date between ? and ? + 1
```

Comment: Frank, won't the TRUNC() cause the optimiser to ignore any index on the date field submitted_date. FWIW, i'd put brackets around the ? + 1 too just to make it obvious what I was doing.

Comment: You're right, trunc() will indeed do that (unless you've got a function-based index on trunc(submitted_date)).

Comment: See the comments under Ollie's answer for what was really going on.  For completeness, using trunc() did not affect performance.  And using `between` was going to work because it's not semantically equivalent (`between` implies `<=` when we needed `<` on the `+1` date).